# NextJS intl set wrong font changing locale

Tags: next.js, fonts, locale, intl, switching

I'm using NextJS v.14 with "next-intl": "^3.4.2", and in the main layout.js file

```
import { Raleway } from 'next/font/google'

const font = Raleway({ subsets: ['latin', 'cyrillic', 'cyrillic-ext'] })

export default function RootLayout({ children, params: { locale } }) {
  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <body className={font.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I have 3 locales - bg (default), ua, en.
Everything switches well but when I am on "/bg" the font looks incorrect (middle photo).

Repo - https://github.com/Aleksandr-Pod/stream_trade/tree/Bug-/bg-prefix

[image: screen shots]

Comment: I tried an additional locale /fr with the same Bulgarian text and the problem is only in /bg prefix. I changed /bg prefix to /bulg in middleware and JSON file and that shows correctly. I blows my mind - what is the matter with that /bg ?